# iterate over multiple global lists and a counter : for / while

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, iteration

I am trying to find a way to iterate over multiple lists and a counter but can't seem to do.

1. I want that every print touches every item in both lists with each counter value
2. I also want to control the loop by removing letters from alphabets one by one.

#### For example here's what i am trying to do

```
alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numb = [1,2,3]
counter = 0

while (len(alphabets) != 0):
    letter = alphabets[0]
    alphabets.remove(letter)
    for val in numb:
        try:
            print counter, letter, val
        except Exception as e:
          print "Failed with: ", counter, letter, val
    counter = counter + 10
```

Here's the output of this program:

```
0 a 1
0 a 2
0 a 3
10 b 1
10 b 2
10 b 3
20 c 1
20 c 2
20 c 3
```

### and here's what i am expecting to get:

```
0 a 1
0 a 2
0 a 3
10 a 1
10 a 2
10 a 3
20 a 1
20 a 2
20 a 3
```

and so on for b and c too.

So basically iterating 27 times instead of 9 while touching every item once with each counter. I can't seem to get it right without skipping any counters. Any ideas?

### Edit:

This is just an example for maxing out at 20 count. What i am trying to do is to control the **loop with either alphabet or numb  (or both) such that for a list alphabet with n items, it will touch all three values in numb for all n items and the counter, and keeps going n times till there are not enough items in alphabet.**

Comment: Could you extend your expected output for `b`? I'm unsure how high that counter should go, should it stop at 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `counter` is maxing out at the length of `alphabet`:

```
alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numb = [1,2,3]

max_counter = len(alphabets) * 10

while (len(alphabets) != 0):
    counter = 0
    letter = alphabets[0]
    alphabets.remove(letter)
    while counter < max_counter:
        for val in numb:
            print counter, letter, val
        counter += 10
```

However, I would personally write the construct like so:

```
alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numb = [1,2,3]

max_counter = len(alphabets) * 10

for letter in alphabets:
    # range max has to be max + inc to work. 
    for counter in range(0, max_counter, 10):
        for number in numb:
            print counter, letter,number
```

Comment: sounds like a good idea. i will try it out now, the thing however is to keep iterating over the counter with 10 till there are not enough letters left (so no max counter value as such). one approach i thought of is show above where i am getting alphabet's len and removing the letter. We can use either numb or alphabet, it doesn't matter. the point is to touch every letter and number with every count on each iteration.

Comment: I've modified both examples to use `len(alphabet)` to set the max counter value, which means you can have variable length alphabets. Hopefully it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just use three for loops.

```
alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numb = [1, 2, 3]

for letter in alphabets:
    for counter in range(0, 21, 10):
        for val in numb:
            print counter, letter, val
```